# Delete individual legends from subplots in panda

Tags: legend, subplot

I would like to remove legends from individual subplots in panda. I created a bar chart and the #subplots. I would like to keep the titles of each subplot and remove the legends since they show the #same verbiage. I have tried several techniques, and even some that has me calling on each individual #subplot but am sure there is a simple solution. The fourth result image below is the one I need help with.

Here is my code so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as st
import numpy as np

mouse_metadata = "Mouse_metadata.csv"
study_results = "Study_results.csv"

mouse_metadata = pd.read_csv(mouse_metadata)
study_results = pd.read_csv(study_results)

study_data_combined = pd.merge(mouse_metadata,study_results, on= "Mouse ID")
pyma_sd = study_data_combined
pyma_sd.head()
```

[image: Picture of Output 1]

```
pyma_sd_grouped = pyma_sd.groupby(["Drug Regimen"])  

pyma_sd_grouped_mean = pyma_sd_grouped["Tumor Volume (mm3)"].mean()

pyma_sd_grouped_median = pyma_sd_grouped["Tumor Volume (mm3)"].median()

pyma_sd_grouped_variance = pyma_sd_grouped["Tumor Volume (mm3)"].var()

pyma_sd_grouped_std = pyma_sd_grouped["Tumor Volume (mm3)"].std()

pyma_sd_grouped_sem = pyma_sd_grouped["Tumor Volume (mm3)"].sem()

pyma_sd_grouped_stats = pd.DataFrame({ "Mean":pyma_sd_grouped_mean,
                                     "Median": pyma_sd_grouped_median,
                                     "Variance": pyma_sd_grouped_variance, 
                                     "Standard Error of Mean ": pyma_sd_grouped_sem})
print("                             ","Stats of Tumor Volume")
print(pyma_sd_grouped_stats)
```

[image: Picture of Output 2]

```
chart_pyma_sd_grouped_stats = pyma_sd_grouped_stats.plot(kind='bar', rot=50, figsize = (10, 6), 
width = .8)
plt.title("Stats on Drug Regimen")Output 2
plt.xlabel("Drug Regimen")
plt.ylabel("Stats per Drug Regimen")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: Picture of output]

```
axes = pyma_sd_grouped_stats.plot.bar(rot=50, subplots=True, figsize = (10, 6), width = .75,)
axes[1].legend(loc=1)
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image: Picture of output 4]**

Answer (score 2):

Simply supply `legend=False` in your call to `DataFrame.plot.bar`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

speed = [0.1, 17.5, 40, 48, 52, 69, 88]
lifespan = [2, 8, 70, 1.5, 25, 12, 28]
index = ['snail', 'pig', 'elephant', 'rabbit', 'giraffe', 'coyote', 'horse']
df = pd.DataFrame({'speed': speed, 'lifespan': lifespan}, index=index)
axes = df.plot.bar(rot=0, subplots=True, legend=False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Compare the image above to the one generated in the [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html).

Comment: Thank you for your quick response,that worked perfectly...thank you so much!

Comment: @Cmac No worries! Please feel free to [accept and upvote my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly, here is the final result: #Generate individual charts showing number of data points for each treatment regimen using pandas
axes = pyma_sd_grouped_stats.plot.bar(rot=50, subplots=True, figsize = (10, 6), width = .75, legend=False)
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)
plt.suptitle("Individual Stats on Each Drug Regimen")
plt.show()